# Getting twitter users with 1000 followers

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am a java developer and i have worked with a twitter api

twitter4j-2.2.2.jar

Although i can find number of my followers, i want to find using public api the users (not necessarily follow/followed by me) who have more than 1000 followers and one of their follower with atleast 100 followers

I am not sure if i can do it using some REST query or what is the best way to get the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the usernames (screen names) and want to find out which of them have got more than 1000 followers, then you can do something like this:

```
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        User user = twitter.showUser("marissamayer");
        if (user.getStatus() != null) {
            int followers = user.getFollowersCount();
            if (followers>=1000) {
                System.out.println("User "+ user.getScreenName()+" Followers " + user.getFollowersCount());
            }
        } else {
            // the user is protected
            System.out.println("@" + user.getScreenName());
        }
```

Else you can use the Twitter search API for a keyword and get the matching usernames and then use the above code to find out the number of followers:

```
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        int page = 1;
        ResponseList<User> users;
        do {
            users = twitter.searchUsers("search_keyword", page);
            for (User user : users) {
                if (user.getStatus() != null && user.getFollowersCount()>=1000) {
                    System.out.println("@" + user.getScreenName()+" Followers: "+user.getFollowersCount());
                } else {
                    // the user is protected
                    System.out.println("@" + user.getScreenName());
                }
            }
            page++;
        } while (users.size() != 0 && page < 50);
```

Comment: Dude.. i am still stuck... can i try my objective using jQuery only instead of Java ?

Comment: for accessing twitter api using jQ post a different question, however for using api v1.1 u need to use ouath, e.g. get oauth_token (aka 
Access token) using the url: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/tokens-devtwittercom and then use jQ's getJSON method to fetch the data from twitter.API ref: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1

Comment: @vikasing Is searchUsers("search_keyword"...) a way to retrieve random users?